# Laravel Missing Settings got me stuck

Tags: php, laravel, settings

so I´m working in Laravel framework. Today i did try to add a Setting to my GeneralSetting. I ran the seeder i prepared to update my Settings datatable. When it wouldn´t run the seperate Setting seeder i put it into my SettingSeeder that has all the values and migrated everything fresh.
Now to my problem. When running my migration-script it kept giving me an error: "Spatie/LaravelSetting/Exceptions/MissingSettings"

After that i did undo all my changes and try to run fresh migration again. Same Error. Now i talked to my coworker and did all the "composer dump-autoload"/ "php artisan optimize:clear" / "php artisan settings:clear-cache" and few more. But whatever i try to run now it says the same Error:
"Patie/LaravelSetting/Exceptions/MissingSettings - Tried loading settings 'App/Setting..', and following properties not found ..(list of my generalSetting that are usually created with my migration)"

Now I´ve been researching for like 2h and checking the Laravel Docu but i failed to find anything usefull. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

Like stated above i tried multiple commands to clear cache / setting and deleted the changes in my files. I also tried to run my migration script with "db:wipe --force // migrate:refresh --force and optimize:clear".

I expected to run the migration normally after deleting all my changes.

Comment: Have you tried step debugging?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean / how i´d be doing that. My App debugger in my .env is active, if thats what you refering to. Other than that I can´t get it to give me any output besides the missing properties one.

Comment: enable xdebug in a recent version and halt on exceptions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and could not deploy because the MissingSettings exception was getting triggered before (in autodiscovery) before running the migrate command. In my case I went in the previous release and copied just the migration for the default values and ran artisan:migrate and after that I was able to deploy the new version with the new Settings.
In your case, you could populate the Settings table manually and it should work.
I hope this helped.